# SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)) buf has an Additional beginning bytes

Tags: c++, websocket, openssl

I working with windows x64, openssl library in c++ 20 with CMake. I have a websocket server and trying to connect it with this code:

```cpp
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SSL_CTX *ssl_ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    SOCKET sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *host;
    int ret;
    char buf[1024];
    string request;
    string response = "";

    //Initialize Windows Socket
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Initialize SSL
    SSL_library_init();

    //Create SSL context and set the TLS version
    ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //Connect to server
    host = gethostbyname("localhost");
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(unsigned long *) (host->h_addr);

    ret = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Failed to connect.\n");
        return -1;
    }


    //Create SSL object
    ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);

    //Connect the SSL object with the socket
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);

    //Establish TLS connection
    SSL_connect(ssl);

    //Construct and send a WebSocket request
    request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request += "Host: localhost:8080\r\n";
    request += "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
    request += "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
    request += "Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n";
    request += "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n";
    SSL_write(ssl, request.c_str(), request.length());


//Receive a response
    while (true) {
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        int len = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
        response = string(buf, len);
        cout << response << endl;

    }

    //Clean up
    SSL_free(ssl);
    closesocket(sock);
    SSL_CTX_free(ssl_ctx);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

I know the server is sending the correct json object because I can hit the server with a Postman or Curl script and I get the correct json object.

the first response is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
�{"type":"pong"}
```

but `SSL_read()` set the `buf` to "�\xf{"type":"pong"}" and all the messages that recived has that Additional beginning bytes.
**I want to get this "{"type":"pong"}"**.

I try another server and get different byte. how to get response without that bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Websocket pong message (`Upgrade: websocket`). 2 first bytes `�\xf` are `0x00 0x0f`, that is 15, that is the length of the JSON.

```
{"type":"pong"}
```

cURL decoded the pong message in the dump.

Comment: thanks. then how separate the json without that length this is work but I didn't think it's the right way: auto json = response.substr(response.find("{"));

Comment: Google for "Websocket frame parser". Suggesting libraries is off topic here.